# php extension_loaded('memcache') is false, but I can clearly see it running on the server

Tags: php, zend-framework, memcached

here's a grep of ps aux on my dev server

```
498       1575  0.0  0.0 330852   152 ?        Ssl  Jun14   2:58 memcached -d -p 11211 -u memcached -m 64 -c 1024 -P /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid
498       6446  0.0  0.0 330852   152 ?        Ssl  Jul23   1:09 memcached -d -p 11212 -u memcached -m 64 -c 1024 -P /var/run/memcached-2/memcached-2.pid
```

So I can see that it is there, I'm using zend framework with 'Memcached' backend, which is using a the extension_loaded('memcache') to see if it is installed.

Is this because they installed memcached2? but if so why would the extension loaded function fail? I'm not much of a server junkie, but my guess is something went wrong in the installation process?

TL;DR;

Why does extension_loaded('memcache') return false, when memcached is running on the server?

Comment: Where did you get memcached2 from ? Latest release is 1.4.20

Comment: I think my resource just wanted to name the second instance of the daemon as memcached-2 @DanFromGermany

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing the [memcached](http://memcached.org/) service which is running on your server and php extensions ([Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) and [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php)) which required to talk with that running service.

You have to install one or both of that extensions to use memcached inside your application. (I recommend the Memcache(d) one.) After successfully installed the extension(s), check it on your server using the command below:

```
$ php -m | grep memcache
```

If you have both extensions, output would be:

```
 $ php -m | grep memcache
   memcache
   memcached
```

In your case, Zend Framework trying to use **memcache** extension (not **memcached**) which is probably not installed on your box.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know, memcache is not memcached. Check if you are checking proper extension (check for memcached). I don't have much experience, because I've used redis for caching.

link: [Memcache Vs. Memcached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825256/memcache-vs-memcached)

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems as though the php module is missing, but the daemon is running, When I run a php -m I do not see memcache as an installed extension, so I'll need to get that installed.

@mrarm that link did help! but both extension_loaded of memcached, and memcache return false, apparently I do need memcache, but it's daemon is named memcached. Stupid naming!

Comment: No! The server is called `memcached`. There are 2 PHP modules `memcache` and `memcached` which both can access the server. You need to install one of those modules (I prefere `memcached`), to access the `memcached` server.