# Can we Implement Memcached in windows, if not why

Tags: php, memcached, wamp, libmemcache

I have Trying to use MemCached but its showing "class not Found error"

```
$Memcached = new Memcached(); 
$Memcached->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
```

But when i Use Memcache everything works Fine :-

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect("127.0.0.1",11211);
```

I have placed memcache.dll file in php ext directory and enable it in php.ini and i have also installed memcache.exe in windows as a service.

Just want to know what i am missing or what i need to do differently as memcache works like a charm while Memcached is showing error.

EDIT:- 
Memcache is installed and visible in the phpinfo file, thats why memcache is working but memcached is not working.I guess memcached is not feasible with windows.[image]

Comment: is the memcached extension visible in your phpinfo() ?? If not then it is not installed in the correct way.
Try restarting your Web server and also check this link http://zurmo.org/wiki/installing-memcache-on-windows

Comment: This may be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825256/memcache-vs-memcached

Comment: it's not installed. `phpinfo();`...

Comment: Memcache is visible you can see above.