# How to check my Memcache version within the drupal admin panel?

Tags: php, drupal, memcached

I am newbie in PHP and having project based on PHP 7.0 and I don't have any access to the my PHP project's files or codes. I have admin panel's credentials and I want to check the memcache version of it.

How do I find it and where can I find it?

Comment: Which admin panel lol?

Comment: @Blackbam sincere apologies for this but I am having the project based on Drupal PHP.

Comment: Does this help: https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache/issues/2823421 ?

Comment: @Blackbam thanks for the help but I don't have that (IP URL) address and I don't have access to the files. Basically, they are in the different office. Only I am having is super admin access.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that there is both memcached and memcache (the former has the **d** at the end). They are two different services, check this link for more informations:
[Memcache Vs. Memcached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825256/memcache-vs-memcached)

If you have memcached with the drupal [memcache storage](https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache_storage) module installed then you can go in the Status report (Reports -> Status report ) and check for the memcache storage infos.

to reach the status report you can go at this url:

```
 <site_url>/?q=admin/reports/status
```

You should see these informations:

[image]