Memcache not closing connections with close()?
The below code snippet will show 2 current connections present even after running the close() function.
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memecache->connect('unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached.sock:0'); 
$memecache->close();
$currConnections = $memcache->getExtendedStats()["curr_connections"];
echo $currConnections."<br>";
unset($memcache); 

$memcache = new Memcache;
$memecache->connect('unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached.sock:0'); 
$memecache->close();
$currConnections = $memcache->getExtendedStats()["curr_connections"];
echo $currConnections."<br>";
unset($memcache); 

memcached.sock actually shows 3 connections if I set a breakpoint before the script ends:
echo stats | nc -U /var/run/memcached/memcached.sock | grep "STAT curr_connections"
STAT curr_connections 3

Why is the close() function not closing them immedietaly as the documentation suggests as I am not using persistent connections?
note: I did attempt to use persistent connections but those wouldn't ever close and I would get n*2, where n were n is the number of times I opened the script.

memcache is not memcached.

@MarkusZeller please elaborate

@MarkusZeller MemCache is the client library that connects to the memcached server.

Does lsof show the open socket connection?

@Barmar yes, it will show a persistent connection, even if I am not running an active script. And then shows multiple connections if the script is running and breakpoint set.

So lsof -p <PID of PHP process> shows that it has the socket open even after $memcache->close()? Sounds like a bug in the MemCache library.

RIght, I was surprised I see a bunch of
memcached 0 11 memcached memcahe 22u unix 0x00000000091ab3166 0t0 96030 unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached.sock:0'  type=stream

@Barmar Are you sure? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825256/memcache-vs-memcached

@MarkusZeller Both of them are client libraries that connect to the same memcached server.

@Barmar Good to know the difference. Thanks for pointing that out.
