# How to use memcache with php

Tags: php, memcached

I am new to this memcache stuff. I read that it saves lot of time of page load time by caching the database key. I have my php application and I want to use memcache as it takes too much time for my application to retrieve the whole set of results from database.

Answer (score 21):

Steps to take:
Prerequisite: read the manual (at least a bit): http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php and make sure you've got memcached installed.

1 Start the memcached program so there is a server that actually stores the key-value pairs.

2 Make a memcache object

3 Store a value for a key

4 Retrieve your key.

```
$memcache = new Memcache; //point 2. 
$memcache->set($yourUniqueKey,  $yourValue, false, 3600); //point 3
//later:
$memcache->get($yourUniqueKey); //point 4.
```

Comment: Hmm. for some reason I can't get the formatting to work this morning. sorry :(

Comment: what should i do if i want to use memcached while hosting my application in a public domain

Comment: Wat do you mean, 'in a public domain' ? On a shared server?

Comment: i meant something like that where we host our website. I am sorry that i am bad at terms

Comment: well, you have to have memcached installed and running. You should take that up with your host, if they support that.

Comment: You should also make sure you understand that memcache and memcached are similar, but independent extensions.  See this other stackoverflow thread for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442411/using-memcache-vs-memcached-with-php

Comment: @Nanne: Are you aware if Memcache(d) can be run on shared servers? In particular, GoDaddy's shared Linux hosting?

Comment: I'm not sure where you are going with that? The whole "and what to do on a shared server" discussion seems a rather strained extention of the initial question "how does memcache(d) work", I don't think there's a need to make a "how to help someone fix memcache(d) on their godaddy server" tutorial in the comments? :D

Comment: I had to add 
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
to get the above to work right.