# How to store an object in Memcache and how to retrieve it using PHP

Tags: php, memcached

I am doing a project using MVC architecture. I am maintaining all the values in session. One of my senior developer tell me that it is not a right procedure to do and he suggest me store all the values in cache.

Is he right? If yes, how can I do that using php...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use memcache with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779523/how-to-use-memcache-with-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Memcache is not the answer for everything, but can dramatically increase page loads for web applications that have lots of load.

The concept is to store your data as key-value pairs in memory (a memcache) and retrieve the data using a key whenever necessary.

Here is a quick example of setting and retrieving data from memcache in PHP:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('192.168.1.2', 11211) or die ("Unable to connect");
$memcache->set(‘key1’, 'value1');   // Set some data
$memcache->get('key1');  // Get some data
```

Read up on some of this:

http://papermashup.com/using-memcache-with-php/

http://fschiettecatte.wordpress.com/2008/05/15/to-use-or-not-to-use-memcached-that-is-the-question/

http://www.majordojo.com/2007/03/memcached-howto.php

Good luck, let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: Can value be a php object?

Answer (score 1):

Read 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php