# MYSQL requests should I group them or not

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have one page that has to get data from 1 db, 3 tables. I use php/mysql.

Right now, each time the page needs data, it'll call a function which create a new connection, get the specific data and close the connection.

Should I make it this way in order to increase loading time ? Will it be noticeable ?

When the page loads, it would call a function to create a new connection, get the data from the 3 tables, put them in an array, return it.  Then I would use the array to parse data where needed. In order to decrease the number of connection/close.

Also, should I use one array for the 3 tables, return it out of the function, split it.
Or use 1 array for each table and return 3 arrays out of the function.

Everything works right now but I'm concern with loading time.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Generally (and there are, as always, exceptions), the best solution is the one that requires the fewest 'round trips' to the MySQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should maybe specify what kind of tables are those. Are they connected with foreign keys or are they completely unrelated?

In general, the connection should be opened for the whole communication with the database, but as shortly as possible. So the workflow should look like:

1. Do stuff (e.g. prepare data)
2. Open connection
3. Work with database
4. Close connection
5. Do stuff (e.g. process data)

**Assuming it is 3 selects with no relation and you need them all at once:**

You should open connection to the database and do the selects separately returning array for each of them. It seems like an overhead to put them in one and then parse them. Finally, you should close the connection.

**Assuming the tables are related:**

You should use join and get the data in one select.

**Assuming that 3 selects would be too expensive and you would need to get all the data in one select:**

You can use union to cluster the data and then pull them in one select and then parse the result. However, it is not very often. Also the readability of the code is worse.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't close the connection, php uses previously opened one.

I think, this is the best workaround. You don't need to fetch array everytime, cause you. may be, don't really need it at all.

Comment: Is that discussed in documentation somewhere?

Comment: Can't find, where did I read this. As I remember, connection closing automatically, when script ends, so, if you use global connection for more then one script, you don't need to open it everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use memcached or redis for load time. 
if you stay connection opened, the connection newer close. And your connection limit will bi exceed.

look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779560/237564

and

http://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-redis-in-php-using-predis/