# What's the best way to set the compression flag for individual set() calls in php's memcached?

Tags: php, compression, memcached, pecl

I'm migrating from [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) to [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) and one of the differences I've noticed is that the compression flag seems to be set for **all** `set()` calls, not on an individual basis like with `memcache`.

Is this a per-connection setting, or can I toggle this on and off? If it's the latter, what would be the best way to go about setting the compression flag for each `set()` call?

Currently I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
<?php
    if ($compress) $mc->setOption(Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION,true);

    $return = $mc->set($key,$object,$expiration);

    if ($compress) $mc->setOption(Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION,false);
```

Is this the right approach?

I'm also setting up `$mc` like this, if it makes any difference:

```
<?php
    $mc = new Memcached("cl");
    $mc->setOption(Memcached::OPT_LIBKETAMA_COMPATIBLE,true);
    $mc->setOption(Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL,true);

    if (count($mc->getServerList()) === 0) {
        $mc->addServers(array (
            array ($GLOBALS["mc"]["host"],$GLOBALS["mc"]["port"]),
        ));
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested in caching techniques. Why do you switch to memcached - what are the advantages. Just quick list or link would be great. thanks

Comment: @NickSoft, here's a good article on that :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442411/using-memcache-vs-memcached-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at the signature of the [two](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php) [methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php) and also reading the source of Memcached, I think it is not possible to set it for each `set`.

See *php-memcached-dev* on github, look for `php_memcached.c`

(What a stupid name for the client by the way. Memcached used to mean the server daemon, now it means server and client, you just can't google it any more.)

Comment: Good to know... Sucks since I store some already compressed binary data in there, as well as strings, ints etc.

Comment: and Memcached doesn't handle them automagically? does it return raw compressed data? if so, amybe you can get them all and save them again with Memcached http://www.darkcoding.net/software/memcached-list-all-keys/

Comment: I don't follow. The data are png and jpeg images, so it seems pointless to me to compress them while set()ting them in MC :-)