# Can't get Memcached working in PHP

Tags: php, apache, memcached

Having issues using the PHP memcached class.

I am running a LAMP environment on Ubuntu 10.10 with Apache 2.2.16 and PHP 5.3.3.
I have just installed what I thought was memcached, but seems possibly to be memcache?

I can start a new memcache object with:

```
$m = new Memcache;
```

Which works fine. But when I try and start a memcached object

```
$m = new Memcached();
```

I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found
```

When I run 'ps -A | grep Memcache' through the console, it returns

```
ben@ben-computer:/tmp$ ps -A | grep memcache
1214 ?        00:00:00 memcached
```

Showing a running memcached process.
phpinfo() returns memcache version 2.2.6.

But when I look further into etc folder

```
ben@ben-computer:/etc/default$ cat memcached 
# Set this to no to disable memcached.
ENABLE_MEMCACHED=yes
```

Then when i run php -m it returns memcache.

You kind of get the picture, i have no idea why memcache is running instead of memcached, any help would be great.

Edit:

I think it could be an issue with libmemcached. I installed the libmemcached-dev package, but not sure if that's the same?

Comment: @hakre, there is a PHP class called Memcached as well.

Comment: The classname is called [`Memcache`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcache.php) or are you using a different extension? Like [`Memcached`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php)? You then need to install the *Memcached* extension, not the *Memcache* extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memcached extension is not a standard component of PHP, and must be installed separately from PECL. Instructions are online at:

http://php.net/memcached.installation

Answer (score 2):

Memcache = name of class
Memcached = name of daemon that runs class

Similarly, `cron` and `crond`, `mysql` and `mysqld`.

Comment: But PHP have a whole section on the Memcached class http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php, the one I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 2):

There are [two different PHP classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442411/using-memcache-vs-memcached-with-php) that you can use. I recommend [memcached](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) over [memcache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) because it is newer and supports more features.

Comment: Thank you Xeoncross, there are two different classes. I want to use the Memcached class but can only use the Memcache class. Any ideas why it might not work?

Comment: @Ben, you need to install it. Read the [memcached installation guide](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/memcached.setup.php) to see how.