# Memcached with row data that change constantly

Tags: mysql, django, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I have a question that I didn't find an answer. Yet ;-)

I have a Django/MySQL application that runs memcached in the background. One of my tables change every access. I mean, when the user access the page I have a "*count*" field that is incremented, this same table contains all data that is going to be displayed.

Is recommended to use memcached in this scenario? Or should I create a new relation table that will contain only "*id*" and "*count*" field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's a valid use for memcached.  The basic rule is that anytime you `update`, or `delete` in the mysql sense of the words, you need to do something to keep the memcache record consistent.  Usually that is done by either adjusting the value right there, or deleting it so the next access of it builds it and saves it.

In your case, I would just `get` the value, increment it, and then `set` it.  Depending on how important accuracy is to you, and how much concurrent traffic you get, you should consider atomicity of the transactions outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626904/php-atomic-memcache) post.