# How to I switch from Memcache to Memcached?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, memcached

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Memcache vs Memcached with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442411/using-memcache-vs-memcached-with-php)

I'm using AWS Elasticache and I've installed there php module which I believe is an extension of spymemcached. The catch is I believe I'm running memcache and not memcached. This is the code to create the object:

```
$memcached = new Memcached();
$memcached->setOption(Memcached::OPT_CLIENT_MODE, Memcached::DYNAMIC_CLIENT_MODE);
$memcached->addServer('goneglobalcache-1a.expalp.cfg.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com', 11211);
$memcached->set('key', 'value', 60);
```

When I go to write to the cache I can't use compression settings and was advised the problem is I'm using a memcache client.

Is there a way to tell which type of client I'm using and a way to switch?

Comment: How would one switch from memcache to memcached? They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Memcache, you need to install (compile) that PHP extension.

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->set('key', 'value', MEMCACHE::COMPRESSED, 60);
```

But note that Memcache compression uses `zlib` which need to be installed.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one Memcached server in the world. But there are two PHP client libraries, one named "Memcache", the other "Memcached".

There are differences: [When should I use Memcache instead of Memcached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442411/using-memcache-vs-memcached-with-php)

Which one you'll need should be documented in the software's requirements.