# Memcached Xampp Windows7

Tags: php, caching, memcached, zend-framework2

I have big problems getting memcached to work under xampp on windows 7. I ve sucessfully loaded the memcache.dll and its shown in php_info. I also started the memcached.exe an its running in taskmanager. But when i want to use Memcached i get the following exception "Need ext/memcached version >= 1.0.0'".
Iam a little bit confused. The Version is greater than 1.0.0.

I ve been searching the whole day for an easy to use installation tutorial for memcached.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, memcache and memcached are different php extensions which written by different groups and both uses memcached service. While memcached extension providing more modern interface to interact with the memcached, it requires libmemcached library which doesn't fully supported on windows. This is why that official extension doesn't exist for windows.

You need to try to find a compiled version of libmemcached which fits your computer's architecture or compile your own (probably it will hard and tricky) or go with memcache extension instead of memcache"d" on windows

Environment (especially windows) specific tricky problems like this is main reason of why i'm using mac (and linux) for quite some time. There are lot of SO questions, mailing/forum threads, github issues about this subject:

[When should I use Memcache instead of Memcached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442411/using-memcache-vs-memcached-with-php)

http://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/71

http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/libmemcacheddll-32-bit-and-64-bit-php-extensions