# Laravel + PHP 7 + Windows + Memcached extension (Class 'Memcached' not found)

Tags: php, windows, laravel, memcached

I´m struggling for about 2 days on this... SO and Googling doesnt help me either.

**Problem:**
When I try to access any page on my newly configured Laravel installation, I get the following message:

```
Class 'Memcached' not found
```

**My enviroment**

- Windows 7
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 7.1.8 (TS, x86, Apache module)

if I execute on command line:

```
λ php -i | grep memcache
memcache
memcache support => enabled
memcache.allow_failover => 1 => 1
memcache.chunk_size => 32768 => 32768
memcache.compress_threshold => 20000 => 20000
memcache.default_port => 11211 => 11211
memcache.hash_function => crc32 => crc32
memcache.hash_strategy => consistent => consistent
memcache.lock_timeout => 15 => 15
memcache.max_failover_attempts => 20 => 20
memcache.protocol => ascii => ascii
memcache.redundancy => 1 => 1
memcache.session_redundancy => 2 => 2
Registered save handlers => files user memcache
```

After some googling, I found out that Laravel requires module memcached (yeah... with a final D). So the module that I managed to load, will not work with laravel.

On this SO post ([Class 'Memcached' not found-(php 5.4.9,windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497463/class-memcached-not-found-php-5-4-9-windows-7)), @rockerBOO said that this module wasnt built for windows, and it "should" work if someone compile it...

My resources ended... I didnt found that module DLL, and I have no idea on how to compile it myself.

Anyone knows anything new about this? Or perhaps, could pinpoint me on how to do it myself??

Thx anyway!

Comment: this could help https://commaster.net/content/installing-memcached-windows?

Comment: It could be worth looking into using Laravel Homestead, and running your environment inside a VM https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead

Comment: another approach could be install Docker and then run memcached as a Container, very easy to setup.

Comment: @MacBooc, that article shows how to install the same module that I already have... I´m looking for a module named memcacheD.

Comment: @LeonardoCabré, actually, memcached is running on my windows... it works really well. The problem is to find that module named memcached for PHP7+windows...

Comment: Do yourself a favor and give Redis a shot. More powerful and more community support as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone facing this problem, I found a workaround.
There´s a package that uses the php_memcache library (yeah, without D).

This library has dll compiled (for php7), and ready to download here:

```
https://github.com/nono303/PHP7-memcache-dll
```

And the package for laravel 5 can be downloaded here:

```
https://packagist.org/packages/swiggles/memcache
```

Follow instructions to install both, and your´re ready to go!

Answer (score 1):

Memcached on Windows doesn't exist, but you can replace it with Memcache on your development environment.

The `get` function works the same, for the `set` you need to change the parameters order:

```
if(!class_exists('Memcached')) {
    class Memcached extends Memcache
    {
        public function set($key, $var, $expire = null)
        {
            /**
             * @see http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php
             * @see http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php
             */
            parent::set($key, $var, null, $expire);
        }
    }
}
```