# Memcached problems on my Mac OS

Tags: php, macos, xampp, localhost, memcached

I just installed memcached on my Mac OS. It installed perfectly and when I type in memcached in Terminal I get this:

```
failed to listen on TCP port 11211 tcp
listen: Address already in use
```

And I have a script in my localhost that contains this:

```
$memcache = new Memcache();
But I get an error thrown saying Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found.
```

How can I get memcached to work, is it because the port 11211 is not listened to which probably doesn't make memcached work?

When I `sudo pecl install memcache` it shows

**pecl/memcache is already installed and is the same as the released version 2.2.7 install failed**

Comment: Have you checked that `memcached` hadn't already been started? Chances are it had. As for the "Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found."  error - it has nothing to do with `memcached` being up and running or not. One more thing: `memcache` and `memcached` are not the same thing. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442411/when-should-i-use-memcache-instead-of-memcached) out for more info.

Comment: $memcache = new Memcached; and $memcache = new Memcache; both are not working 

I try this command ps -e | grep memcache | grep -v grep it shows 
21476 ??         0:00.14 /usr/local/bin/memcached -d -p 11211
23196 ??         0:00.05 memcached -d -p 8000

AND netstat -a -p tcp | grep LISTEN

Comment: @mrun When I run sudo pecl install memcache

It shows pecl/memcache is already installed But when i run the script it shows Fatal  error

Comment: It's installed but is it enabled in php.ini? You can find out by running `php -m | grep memcache` and see if there are any entries.